# replace every single string value with 0

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

given this dataframe, I want to replace every single string value in a column with the value 0.
I tried this code but the dataframe remains unaffected.
I am not sure how to change the parameters of this line

```
df['new'].replace(to_replace=r'^$', value=0, regex=True)
```

here is the whole code:

```
l2=['a. 12','b. 75','23', 'sc/a 34', '85', 'a 32', 'b 345']
d = {'col1': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col1']=l2

df['new'] = np.where(df["col1"].str.isnumeric(),df["col1"].str[:], (df["col1"].str.extract("^([a-z/]*)", expand=False)) )
print(df['new'])
df['new'].replace(to_replace=r'^$', value=0, regex=True)
print(df['new'])
```

so the dataframe column should have the following values:

0  0  23  0  85  0  0

Comment: This regular expression: `^$` will match only for empty strings. Also calling directly replace without supplying inplace=True might not produce the results you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try `to_replace='^', value=0, regex=True, inplace=True`.

That is: if the regex matches then it must be a string, so replace with number 0.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

PS If you want to strip non-numeric characters and *all* numbers are integers, then this might be what you want:

```
df['new'].replace(to_replace=r'\D+', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

That is: in every value (all your values in the example are strings) replace any sequence of non-digits with the empty string.

Comment: unfortunately with your solution the column dataframe remains unchanged as well

Comment: My previous answer was indeed incorrect.

Comment: I tried it, it does not work

Comment: Did you try with `bla.replace(…inplace=True)` or `bla = bla.replace(…)`?

Comment: bla = bla.replace(…) works but it replaces every single item with 0, that is probably because even the numbers are a string type

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to strip anything non-digit? That is, change 'a. 12' to '12', 'sc/a 34' to '34' etc?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your regex represent an empty string :

> nothing between start (^) and end ($) of string.

You should use  : `.*`